# Topping up customer balance for use in small transactions

Tags: stripe-payments

We're hoping to use stripe to handle our payment scenario for an upcoming product.

I've been unable to discern if and how this is supported by Stripe, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Our workflow is as follows:

1. A customer signs up for our service with a credit card and tops up their account with a set amount, say £10, £20, or £50.
2. The customer uploads some data our platform to be processed, with a fixed price per row. For example, 10p per row.
3. As the data is processed, we deduct the cost from their balance.
4. When their balance gets to zero, we stop processing their data, at which point they can top-up their account again.
5. If/when they top-up, we resume processing their data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds very straightforward.

> A customer signs up for our service with a credit card and tops up their account with a set amount, say £10, £20, or £50

This results in Stripe telling you "you have received £20 from this customer" (via a webhook or otherwise, depending on your integration path). You can now update your DB and enable features (row processing and whatnot).

```
UPDATE users
SET balance = balance + 20 * 100
WHERE customer_id = 'cus_1234'
```

As you process rows, you subtract from customer's balance. When it runs out, you prompt the customer to topup again.

As you can see, Stripe has virtually nothing to do with all this. But it will handle actual money collection, the important part. :)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Would we be able to use the Stripe Customer Balance feature as it says in the docs that this is a ledger that we can issue transactions against?

Comment: @arrkaye: well, it's part of subscriptions (what stripe calls "Billing"). You have to pay extra for this. And what would be the benefit? I feel that tracking usage/balance entirely on your side will be easier/faster.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe provides documentation on what they call "Metered Billing." This should cover your use case since you are charging per upload. Here are the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/metered-billing).

Comment: That's subscriptions and post-pay. Looks like the question is about another scenario.